# Ubuntu 20.04 boot shows 2 Windows 10 options as /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10.

**For command :** *sudo update-grub*
**Output:**

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda2
done
```

Why it is showing two options for Windows rather 1?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: If you have BIOS boot and ran Boot-Repair, it copies the essential Windows boot files from sda1 to sda2. Windows BIOS boots from primary NTFS partition with boot flag. But grub does not use boot flag and just looks for the Windows boot files. So many users deleted the Windows boot partition, that Boot-Repair backs up the boot files into the main Windows partition, just in case.

Comment: @oldfred That comment is better than many answers, thanks!